# Parallelizing multiple long-running tasks with async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a helper method returns `IEnumerable<string>`. As the collection grows, it's slowing down dramatically. My current approach is to do essentially the following:

```
var results = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    results.Add(await item.Fetch());
}
```

I'm not actually sure whether this asynchronicity gives me any benefit (it sure doesn't *seem* like it), but all methods up the stack and to my controller's actions [are asynchronous](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4):

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> FetchAllItems()
```

As this code is ultimately used by my API, I'd really like to parallelize these all for what I hope would be great speedup. I've tried .AsParallel:

```
var results = items
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(i => i.Fetch().Result)
    .AsList();
return results;
```

And .WhenAll (returning a string[]):

```
var tasks = items.Select(i => i.Fetch());
return Task<string>.WhenAll<string>(tasks).Result;
```

And a last-ditch effort of firing off all long-running jobs and sequentially awaiting them (hoping that they were all running in parallel, so waiting on one would let all others nearly complete):

```
var tasks = new LinkedList<Task<string>>();
foreach (var item in items)
    tasks.AddLast(item.Fetch());

var results = new LinkedList<string>();
foreach (var task in tasks)
    results.AddLast(task.Result);
```

In every test case, the time it takes to run is directly proportional to the number of items. There's no discernable speedup by doing this. What am I missing in using Tasks and `await`/`async`?

Comment: Async will not give you benefits of improved performance of your algorithm, rather, it will allow your main thread (UI) to remain responsive while the work is being done.

Comment: If you tasks CPU bound you should see speedup proportional to number of CPUs, unless your code have something (like large chunks of code under shared `lock`) that completely prevents it to run in parallel or CPU is already at 100% due to other processing.

Comment: @JohnKoerner: Wouldn't `.AsParallel` give speedup for these async tasks? I originally started looking at tweaking my `foreach` to a `Parallel.ForEach`, then I wandered off a bit into the async/await world.

Comment: Yes, `AsParallel` will allow you to use more threads to accomplish the task.  Using something like a `ConcurrentBag` may help, also run your tests in Release mode to determine the actual performance of your code.

Comment: Have you fully profiled this code? The finding that there's no discernable speedup even when you parallelize this specific function suggests that the issue may lie elsewhere.

Comment: What exactly is `Fetch` doing? Does it execute IO bound work or CPU bound work?

Comment: @furkle: `Fetch` is an IO-bound process. It downloads some data from a remote server.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between *parallel* and *concurrent*. Concurrency just means doing more than one thing at a time, whereas parallel means doing more than one thing *on multiple threads*. `async` is great for concurrency, but doesn't (directly) help you with parallelism.

As a general rule, parallelism on ASP.NET should be avoided. This is because any parallel work you do (i.e., `AsParallel`, `Parallel.ForEach`, etc) shares the same thread pool as ASP.NET, so that reduces ASP.NET's capability to handle *other* requests. This impacts the scalability of your web service. It's best to leave the thread pool to ASP.NET.

However, concurrency is just fine - specifically, asynchronous concurrency. This is where `Task.WhenAll` comes in. Code like this is what you should be looking for (note that there is no call to `Task<T>.Result`):

```
var tasks = items.Select(i => i.Fetch());
return await Task<string>.WhenAll<string>(tasks);
```

Given your other code samples, it would be good to run through your call tree starting at `Fetch` and replace all `Result` calls with `await`. This may be (part of) your problem, because `Result` forces synchronous execution.

Another possible problem is that the underlying resource being fetched does not support concurrent access, or there may be throttling that you're not aware of. E.g., if `Fetch` retrieves data from another web service, check out `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`.

Comment: Perhaps I am just not grokking `async`/`await` and I want to see the result itself in the debugger rather than the Task. If my whole call chain (all the way through to the controller's action) is `async`, can I simply implement `WhenAll` (as in your code example) and improve performance over my current `foreach` implementation?

Comment: Yes, as long as the underlying resource permits concurrent access and there's no throttling.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a configurable limitation on the max connections to a single server that can make download performance independent to the number of client threads.

To change the connection limit use
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit

[Maximum concurrent requests for WebClient, HttpWebRequest, and HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516598/maximum-concurrent-requests-for-webclient-httpwebrequest-and-httpclient)