# Programming HttpClient for high performance

Tags: .net, .net-core

I setup an Azure website that just returns [the default page](https://testinghttpclient.azurewebsites.net/). The response time calling this link from .Net Core 2.1 is a few milliseconds. I then try to send 1000 concurrent requests using HttpClient. The batch completes on average in 27 seconds.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(i => Get(i)));
    }

    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static async Task Get(int i)
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://testinghttpclient.azurewebsites.net/");
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

27 seconds per 1000 requests seems too slow to me. Am I using HttpClient correctly? If so, can you please help me understand what my limiting resource is in this situation?

Comment: have you measured time without `ReadAsStringAsync` ?

Comment: btw your code runs on my network just for 00:00:02.1045089 
so it really depends on your network capacity

Comment: Thanks Veikedo. That was it -- it was my local network that was limiting bandwidth.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that [there are concurrency limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516598/maximum-concurrent-requests-for-webclient-httpwebrequest-and-httpclient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was running this from the IDE. Publishing it in the release mode and running it from the command line brought the execution to under a second.

Comment: thanks for the update, I was puzzling over this one. Were you using Visual Studio to accomplish this task?