# Why do I have a .NET Core API performance issue using IHttpClientFactory when ramping up users?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, .net-core, aws-xray

I have a .NET Core WebAPI my React UI is calling to Authenticate Users.  It calls a 3rd Party API for this.  Everything works fine but we have started to do Performance testing on it and it is not scaling well when we ramp up the Users attempting to log on concurrently. (taking 30 secs)

The 3rd Party API we call are saying they are responding in milliseconds.

My API is hosted in Kubertnetes container on AWS.  I have added AWS X-ray to the code to try and get further information though I am not really sure on how to interpret the results.

The code is quite straightforward - This is a snippet from MyAuthenticationProvider class (the constructor takes a metric collector (for AWS X-Ray and and securityProvider http client for making the call)

```
        metricCollector.StartCollection("Stage 1");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await securityProvider.SendAsync(requestMessage);
        metricCollector.EndCollection();
```

The X-Ray image for the above code is:

[image]

Is X-Ray showing that it is indeed waiting 30+ Seconds for this API to return a response and I should reach out to that company for further investigation on there side even though they are telling me all traffic is getting responded too in milli-seconds.

Or could it be how I have defined the http client used in MyAuthProvider class in Startup.cs that is not scaling correctly when the concurrent users ramps up?

This is the code for that in Startup.cs

```
      services.AddTransient<IMyAuthenticationProvider>(ctx =>
        {
            IHttpClientFactory clientFactory = ctx.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            return new MyAuthenticationProvider(
                clientFactory.CreateClient("3RDPARTYAUTHCLIENT"),
                ctx.GetService<IMetricCollector>());
        });
```

Another thing I was thing to improve performance is introducing Redis to cache some of these responses as they are getting calling multiple times for different operations but the result will be the same

Comment: One thing to note is that `HttpClient`, by default, will only permit something like 6 conccurent requests to a given endpoint. So if your load is more than 6 requests/(time for downstream API to respond) they will start backing up. You can increase the number of concurrent HTTP requests (e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39520881/15393))

Comment: @RB. - thanks for the link - readinhg here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/managing-connections?redirectedfrom=MSDN - says ServicePoint is considered legacy in .NET Core 5?  I dont know if that means it should be solved in it

Comment: think I can set it here though - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=net-5.0

Comment: What is the lifecycle of MyAuthenticationProvider? Is the controller constructing it and invoking it each time? Any reason for registering it as transient?

Answer (score 3):

While you're only creating 1 named `HttpClient`, you've set the  service lifetime of `IMyAuthenticationProvider` to **transient**.

This means that essentially you're losing out on most of the benefits of a single `HttpClient` by creating a **new** instance of `IMyAuthenticationProvider` **every time something requests for one** (which in the best-case scenario, will be synonymous with every client request but not to be mistaken with scoped services).

This can massively slow down your application & may be the cause of the badly performing scaling of the application.

You're trying to clearly use a single `HttpClient`, which would typically be `static` or wrapped as a non-static instance inside a singleton class. and is still [a good solution for short-lived console applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient) etc. however in this case I'd allow `IHttpClientFactory` to resolve the client.

The primary goal of IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core is to ensure that HttpClient instances are created appropriately ([taking into account things like DNS changes](http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html) which a single `HttpClient` instance won't take care of) while at the same time eliminating socket exhaustion.

Injected `HttpClient` instances by `IHttpClientFactory` have a [transient lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) (documentation is conflicting & mentions transient 2x & scoped 1x for some absurd reason) and so I'd **set the lifetime of `IMyAuthenticationProvider` to scoped to allow it to be reused as much as possible**.

Having a longer running singleton `IHttpClientFactory`, in this case, with an injected shorter-lived scoped `HttpClient` should not be done.

[MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes):

> Do not resolve a scoped service from a singleton and be careful not to do so indirectly

While the injected `HttpClient` object is transient, using the `IHttpClientFactory` enables pooling of `HttpMessageHandler` objects that can and will be reused by multiple `HttpClient` instances.

Try:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyAuthenticationProvider, MyAuthenticationProvider>();
services.AddHttpClient<IMetricCollector, MetricCollector>();
...

services.AddScoped<IMyAuthenticationProvider, MyAuthenticationProvider>();
```

```
public class MyAuthenticationProvider : IMyAuthenticationProvider
{
  private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

  public MyAuthenticationProvider(HttpClient httpClient)
  {
      _httpClient = httpClient;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: ill give that a go

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat Let me know :)

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat Did this sort your issue or is it something else? I'm curious! :)

Comment: I haven't refactored as you suggested just yet.  I am going to run another stress test just with the MaxConnectionsPerServer property updated